# Find $T(x,y,z)$ if $T:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^3$ given that basis and the representation matrix, difference between 2 methods

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

> Find $T(x,y,z)$ if $T:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^3$ given that basis $B=((1,1,0), (0,1,1), (1,1,1))$ and
>   $$
> [T]_B=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0\\0&1&0\\-1&0&2\end{pmatrix}
> $$

As far as I understand there're 2 methods for doing this. I will show the method I know $(1)$ and the method that I saw in the solution $(2)$. The final answers are different so I'd like to know whether only one method is correct, different answers are possible or I made a mistake.

**My method 1 (possibly correct):**

Express $(x,y,z)$ as a linear combination of the basis $B$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&x\\1&1&1&y\\0&1&1&z\end{pmatrix}\to \begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&x\\0&1&0&y-x\\0&1&1&z\end{pmatrix}\to\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&x\\0&1&0&y-x\\0&0&1&z-y-x\end{pmatrix}\to\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&2x-z+y\\0&1&0&y-x\\0&0&1&z-y-x\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now we want to find the images of $(x,y,z)$ according to $[T]_B$:
$$
[T]_B\cdot [(x,y,z)]_B=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0\\0&1&0\\-1&0&2\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}2x-z+y\\y-x\\z-y-x\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}y-x\\y-x\\-4x+3z-3y\end{pmatrix}
$$
Let $\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$ be the vectors of the basis $B$ in their order.

Then $T(x,y,z)=(y-x)b_1+(y-x)b_2+(-4x+3z-3y)b_3=$
$$
=(y-x)(1,1,0)+(y-x)(0,1,1)+(-4x+3z-3y)(1,1,1)=\\
=(y-x,y-x,0)+(0,y-x,y-x)+(-4x+3z-3y,-4x+3z-3y,-4x+3z-3y)=\\
=(-5x-2y+3z,-6x-5y+3z,-5x-2y+3z).
$$

---

**Method 2 (the correct one):**
I don't even know what is the meaning of this stage $\ast$, I guess we're getting the images of the vectors from $B$ (even though we already know that $T((1,1,0)=(0,0,-1)$ etc.):
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1\\1&1&1\\0&1&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
T(1,1,0)=B\cdot[T(v_1)]_B=B\cdot(0,0,-1)=-(1,1,1)\\
T(0,1,1)=B\cdot[T(v_2)]_B=B\cdot(1,1,0)=(1,2,1)\\
T(1,1,1)=B\cdot[T(v_3)]_B=B\cdot(0,0,-1)=(2,2,2)
$$
Now we find the vectors according to standard basis:
$$
T(1,0,0)=T(1,1,1)-T(0,1,1)=(2,2,2)-(1,2,1)=(1,0,1)
$$
Similarly:
$$
T(0,1,0)=(-2,-1,-2)\\T(0,0,1)=(3,3,3)
$$
Finally:
$$
T(x,y,z)=T(x(1,0,0)+y(0,1,0)+z(0,0,1))=\\
=x(1,0,1)+y(-2,-1,-2)+z(3,3,3)=\\
=(x-2y+3z,-y+3z,x-2y+3z)
$$
**Please explain** whether my method is incorrect and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following sentence is wrong

> I guess we're getting the images of the vectors from $B$ (even though we already know that $T(1,1,0)=(0,0,−1), \ T(1,1,0)=(0,0,−1)$ etc.)

Indeed $T(1,1,0)$ is equal to $(0,0,-1)$ **in the base $B$**, which is actually $(-1, -1, -1)$.

But your first method seems correct. However you made a sign mistake in the third matrix, the bottom right element should be $z-y+x$. I think this changes things a lot and might lead to the correct result.

Comment: So if $T(1,1,0)=(0,0,-1)$ then we already have an image. So what is $-(1,1,1)$?

Comment: $T(1,1,0)=(0,0,-1)_B=-(1,1,1)$

Comment: I re-did the calculation after you noticed the mistake and it turned out the same! Thanks! I still don't understand the difference between $(0,0,-1)$ and $-(1,1,1)$. They're both images, are they images according to different bases?

Comment: yes, you can represent the same vector in different bases, and therefore they won't have the same coordinates. $-(1,1,1)$ has coordinates $0$, $0$ and $-1$ in the base $B$

Comment: so what is the base of $-(1,1,1)$?

Comment: the "canonical" base of $\mathbb R^3$, $B_c=((1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1))$