# Find the orthogonal basis for $(\operatorname{ker}T)^{\bot}$ given the linear map and representation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, proof-explanation, orthogonality

> Find the orthogonal basis for $(\operatorname{ker}T)^{\bot}$ if $T:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^3$ and
>   $$
> [T]_B=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0\\0&1&0\\-1&0&2\end{pmatrix}
> $$
>   and
>   $$
> T(x,y,z)=(x-2y+3z,-y+3z,x-2y+3z)
> $$
>   This question builds on this question: [Find $T(x,y,z)$ if $T:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^3$ given that basis and the representation matrix, difference between 2 methods](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2349774/find-tx-y-z-if-t-mathbb-r3-to-mathbb-r3-given-that-basis-and-the-repre)

This is the solution:

1) Find the general solution to:
$$
\begin{cases}x-2y+3z=0\\-y+3z=0\end{cases}
$$
which means that $\operatorname{ker}T=\operatorname{span}\{(3,3,1)\}$.

2) Then $v\in (\operatorname{ker}T)^{\bot}\Leftrightarrow 3x+3y+z=0$ so  $(\operatorname{ker}T)^{\bot}=\operatorname{span}\{(1,0,3),(0,1,-3)\}$.

3) Lastly Gram-Shmidt process is used on $\{(1,0,3),(0,1,-3)\}$.

---

My question is:

1) Because $\operatorname{ker}T$ is the null space of the linear map this means that row space is orthogonal to $\operatorname{ker}T$ then don't we get immediately that $(\operatorname{ker}T)^{\bot}$ is just the rows (already linearly independent):
$$
\begin{cases}x-2y+3z=0\\-y+3z=0\end{cases}
$$
So why do we need step 2?

2) Why do we need Gram-Shmidt? Isn't the basis we found in step already orthogonal?

3) Could we find $\operatorname{ker}T$ from finding the solution to the system represented by the matrix $[T]_B$?

If these are too many questions let me know and I'll open them as different ones (although I don't think they're too loaded).

Comment: $(\mathrm{ker}(T))^\perp = \mathrm{im}(T^*)$, so it's spanned by the rows of the matrix representation of $T$; then you could apply Gram-Schmidt to that.

Comment: @DanielSchepler is $(\operatorname{Im}T)^*$ the row space of $[T]_B$ or the row space of the linear system?

Comment: Oh, I didn't look at the previous question - $B$ is not an orthonormal basis so $[T^*]_B$ is not necessarily going to be equal to the transpose of $[T]_B$.  Never mind...

Comment: But if you take the matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard basis, its rows are $(1, -2, 3), (0, -1, 3), (1, -2, 3)$ and indeed the span of these vectors is the same as the span of $(1, 0, -3), (0, 1, -3)$.  (Which by the way pointed out to me that there's a small error in (2) in your solution.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler why exactly $[T]_B$ is not good in this case?

Comment: The theorem $[T^*]_B = ([T]_B)^*$ requires the hypothesis that $B$ is an orthonormal basis.

Comment: @DanielSchepler what does the asterisk mean?

Comment: For $T \in L(V, W)$, $T^* \in L(W, V)$ is the unique linear transformation such that $\langle T^* x, y \rangle = \langle x, T y \rangle$ for all $x \in W, y \in V$; and for a real matrix $A$, $A^*$ is another notation for the transpose $A^T$ (which I chose to use here to avoid confusion with $T$).